Why Land given to God's people
What is the exact translation about God giving the land to his people? What must they do to earn it?

Gen 15:7 - The LORD also told him, “I am the LORD, who brought you out
of Ur of the Chaldeans to give you this land to possess.”
Gen 15:18-21 - On that day the LORD made a covenant with Abram,
saying, “To your descendants I have given this land—from the river of
Egypt to the great River Euphrates— the land of the Kenites,
Kenizzites, Kadmonites, Hittites, Perizzites, Rephaites, Amorites,
Canaanites, Girgashites, and Jebusites.”


Welcome to SE-BH. Your question is unclear to me. What verse are you quoting from, please ? Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of this, an hermeneutic site. Questions which do not reference a portion of text cannot be analysed hermeneutically and such questions may be voted for closure by users or closed by Moderators.

The promise of the land to God's chosen people is contained in Abrahamic Covenant - see appendix below.
The descendants of Abraham did nothing to "earn it" - indeed, that was the point of the covenant with Abraham - he did nothing to earn the land or any other benefits of the covenant - it arose from God's grace and initiated by God alone.
The nation of Israel inherited this promise of the Abrahamic covenant as part of the Israelite covenant (Ex 19-23) which is why they were brought up from the land of Egypt to take possession of the land of Palestine.
APPENDIX - Abrahamic Covenant: Gen 13:14-17, 15:1-17, 17:1-27, 18:9-15, 22:15-18
The Abrahamic Covenant is stated in three places, Gen 15 & 17, are 13 years apart (and repeated in Gen 12:1-3, 13:14-17, 18:9-15, 22:15-18 without using the word “covenant” nor formal sacrifices) and was an eternal covenant, Gen 13:15, 17:9, 13, 19.  The covenant consisted of the following:
Gen 15

God promises Abram a biological son
God promises Abram uncountable descendants
God promises Abram’s descendants the land of Canaan, “from the wadi of Egypt to the great river Euphrates”.
God promises to return Abram’s descendants to Canaan after Egyptian slavery of 400 years
God promises to punish the Egyptians
God promises great possessions to Abram’s descendants when they leave Egypt
The covenant was initiated and signified by a ceremony (significant to the culture of Abraham) of cutting several animals in half and God passing between the halves, and (and so solemnly promising) to keep the provisions of the covenant.

This ceremony of cutting sacrificed animals in half is a direct allusion of the word “berith” (= “covenant”), meaning, “to cut”.  That this covenant was a covenant of grace is confirmed by Gen 15:6, “Abram believed the LORD and he credited it to him as righteousness”.  (See also Rom 4:3, 22, Gal 3:6, James 2:23.)
Gen 17, 18:9-15

God promises a biological son by Sarah, viz. Isaac
God promises to greatly increase Abram’s numbers
God promises Abram that he would be the father of many nations
God promises Abraham the land of Canaan
God promises that Ishmael would also be fruitful
Abraham and his descendants must promise to be faithful to God
The covenant is signified by the token/sign (Heb: “oth”, Gen 17:10, 11, 13, Rom 4:11) of circumcision (= circular cut), Acts 7:8, and a change of name from Abram to Abraham.

It is immediately clear that this covenant is a re-statement, with only slight variations, of the covenant in Gen 15, and was an eternal covenant, Gen 17:7, 13.
NOTE 1: The promise of the land of Canaan, “from the wadi of Egypt to the great river Euphrates” (Gen 15:18) was only ever fulfilled during the time of King Solomon (1 Kings 4:20-25, 2 Chron 9:26).  However, because of Israel’s unfaithfulness, Isaiah prophesied that they would lose all the land (Isa 27:12), which finally happened when Babylon conquered them (2 Kings 24:7).  Israel has never regained all this territory.  See “Israel”.
NOTE 2: The token/sign of the Abrahamic was circumcision (among other things) and their inheritance of the Promised Land, Josh 5:7.  See also Acts 8:7.  There is no indication that circumcision was a sign of the Israelite covenant, although it was used as metaphor of dedication, Deut 10:16, 30:6, Jer 4:4.  Thus, when the circumcision was dispensed with in Acts 15, the Abrahamic covenant was seen by the Christian church as ended - the Jews had rejected God.
NOTE 3: The Abrahamic covenant appears to have been suspended during 38 of the 40 years of wilderness wandering because no one was circumcised during that time.  This was done because the people rejected the covenant of God’s miraculous workings in Num 13 after hearing the spies’ report but them compounded the problem and tried to take the land by human effort alone (Num 14) which failed miserably.  After 40 years, when the new generation of Israelites came to the boarder of Canaan, circumcision was re-instituted according to Josh 5:2-8.

Good answer!  A side question. Since God initiated the covenant and the covenant was not made based on good behavior how is it that the failure to circumcise in the part of the Israelites can suspend the covenant? Is there a verse that indicates God suspended the covenant?

@DavidD - no, there is no such verse - that conclusion about the suspended covenant is simply based purely on what happened.

God makes a covenant to give his people a promised land as a way to restore a personal relationship that was lost.
In Eden, God walked with Adam, but I’m since the exile of Eden we have not had that relationship.
Genesis and Exodus are about selecting a remnant peoples who can be in right relationship with him if they follow his statutes that he sets out in Leviticus.
The promised land that flows with milk and honey is to be an Eden like place where man again can enjoy the fruits of the land without having to toil for it as they did before the curse. A return to Eden and relationship with God.
But all this is a foreshadowing of what needs to take place for man to enjoy this life again in new creation. We can participate in this new life if we put our faith in Jesus who is the fulfillment of the levitical laws, who is the temple made flesh, who is priest, prophet and king.
In the end, all who are in Christ will be join Him in the new heaven and new earth.
